# Different X values for different columns on highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, legend

I have a problem with drawing a highchart like on this fiddle
[Sample highchart](http://jsfiddle.net/z7ebu5fy/). But I want chart like this one, but with many series/labels in legend. I want to get 'Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April' as a different series to filtering the chart. How can I do that?

When I'm using something like this instead of one series I've got 4 series only for first X value. So it's not a solution.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Series1',
        data: [49.9]

    }, {
        name: 'Series2',
        data: [83.6]

    }, {
        name: 'Sereis3',
        data: [48.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Sereis4',
        data: [42.1]

    }]
```

Comment: Do you mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/tLjke7fp/ ?

Comment: Yes, something like this. But it will be great if every column will be center, is it possible?

Comment: You can use pointPlacement parameter with number value. http://jsfiddle.net/o2Lr1dp1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sebastian Bochan. Your comment was very helpful.

This is solution of my problem
http://jsfiddle.net/tLjke7fp/6/

I have only added this code to your solution.

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
        }
    },
```

or

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
        }
    },
```